# Show Results from google place API in PHP

Tags: php, google-api

I need to show all the results from Google place API.

Request:

```
$x = $_POST['lat'];
$y = $_POST['long'];
$StringR="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$x,$y&radius=1500&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBwCNVKStx8rdNuTDif0JuuRvKRxMtoPRQ";
```

I show all the results with :

```
$StringaRR= file_get_contents($StringR);

$StringaRRR=  json_decode($StringaRR);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($StringaRRR);
```

I print only the first result with :

```
$name = $StringaRRR->results[0]->name;
echo "$name";
```

and the variable `$name` return, correctly, the name of first result given by Google Place.

Now I want show, ordered, all the result by name from my request with:

```
$i=0;

foreach($StringaRRR as $namel){
echo $namel->result[$i]->name;
$i=$i+1;
}
```

While the variable `$name` is correctly printed, the print of $namel return this error:
**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: What is `$StringaRR` - the JSON string. Can you add it to this question?

Comment: $StringaRR is a variable that contain the answer given by $StringR(API), I think that is clear what is $StringaRR,or not?

Comment: Yes - I meant can you add a print out of what that string typically looks like. I've no idea what the google API looks like, but you're problem looks like it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future use

I have found the solution, the problem was in the loop foreach, for a correct use instead of *foreach* must be used the *for* like that :

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($StringaRRR->results); $index++) {

echo $StringaRRR->results[$index]->name;
}
```

The previous part of the code are correct.